# Couchbase error opening bucket - Could not bootstrap

Tags: c#, couchbase

I am trying to connect to my couchbase server (Enterprise ver 4.6.2) and open a bucket using the .Net SDK, the code is very simple but still fail to work:

```
        var cluster = new Cluster(new ClientConfiguration
        {
            Servers = new List<Uri> { new Uri("https://10.0.0.54:8091/") }
        });

        try
        {
            var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("default");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error getting bucket.");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

The inner exception details I get:

Message

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

StackTrace

```
Couchbase.IO.Services.PooledIOService.CheckEnabledServerFeatures(IConnection connection)
   at Couchbase.IO.Services.PooledIOService..ctor(IConnectionPool connectionPool)
   at Couchbase.IO.IOServiceFactory.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<GetFactory>b__0(IConnectionPool pool)
   at Couchbase.Configuration.Server.Providers.CarrierPublication.CarrierPublicationProvider.GetConfig(String bucketName, String username, String password)
```

The main exception I see is:

```
Could not bootstrap - check inner exceptions for details.
```

And the stack trace:

```
   at Couchbase.Core.ClusterController.CreateBucket(String bucketName, String username, String password, IAuthenticator authenticator)
   at Couchbase.Core.ClusterController.CreateBucket(String bucketName, IAuthenticator authenticator)
   at Couchbase.Cluster.OpenBucket(String bucketname)
   at Couchbase.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Does the server listen on `https://10.0.0.54:8091`?

Comment: Yes, its accessible from the browser, just from the code it doesn't.

Comment: @JosefBláha Track your request originating from the sdk and check for the response code (Use Fiddler)

Comment: Did you succeed solving this issue? I experience the same behavior..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the Community edition. In my case I had not created the **default** bucket before trying to access it. Also, if your server/cluster or bucket require credentials you need to enter those as well.

Answer (score 0):

Expose all required ports 
docker run -d -p 8091-8096:8091-8096 -p 11210:11210 -p 11211:11211    couchbase